# Why modulus is not considered in this vector algebra problem.

Tags: vectors

> Question: given two vectors $i-j$ and $i+2j$ , the unit vector coplanar with the two vectors and perpendicular to first is
>
> (a)$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} (i+j)$
>
> (b)$\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} (i +j)$

Let given two vectors be a and b, required vector be $r=xi+yj+zk$ then $[a b c]=0$ solving I got z=0. For solving r and a coplanar gives $x=y$.

Now $r=xi +xi$. Then unit vector means $|r|=\sqrt{x^2+x^2}=|x|\sqrt2=\pm x\sqrt2$

Unit vector $r=\dfrac{x(i +j)}{\pm x\sqrt2}=\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2} (i +j)$

But.. answer is option (a). Please explain why modulus is not taken. Or I am missing some concept in vectors.

Comment: Your answer seems completely correct.

Comment: I checked two sources and both says it’s wrong. 1) book 2)[online site](https://www.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/given-two-vectors-i-j-and-i-2j-find-a-unit-vector-coplanar-w/vector-algebra/8869613)

Comment: it is not completely correct!

Comment: Even geometrically is almost trivial to check your answer is correct...The only thing that could be argued is that they ask for "the" vector coplanar...etc, and option (b) has **two** vectors. But this would be ridiculous, imo.

Comment: @Fawad **What** is wrong according to two sources? Your answer or to say (a) is correct?

Comment: @don Answer a is correct

Comment: @Fawad It really is hard to understand you: so you say that two sources both  said option (a) is **wrong** ? Then who did say option (a) is correct? Your teacher, your book...?

Comment: @DON Sorry my bad English. Sources say option a is correct. I think b is correct.

Comment: @Fawad Thanks. Perhaps I, and others, are missing something trivial...

Comment: I think they mean the Normalized Vector.
These 2 are sometimes used the same way.
Hence a) is korrekt.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake seems to be in writing $|x|$ as being the same as $\pm x$ which is not true.

So answer a) is correct

Comment: You are right that $|x| = x$ **or** $|x| = -x$ and the $\pm$ in the usual sense is wrong. But... if $u$ is *a* "unit vector coplanar with the two vectors and perpendicular to first", then $-u$ is *another* unit vector coplanar with the two vectors and perpendicular to first.